# Как создавать архивы при помощи модуля zipfile?

Tags: python, zip

Я начинающий python программист.
Я не могу понять, как создавать архивы при помощи модуля zipfile?
Объясните пожалуйста (если несложно, добавьте пример в виде программы)

Comment: zipfile — Work with ZIP archives  https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile

Comment: Пример покажите, пожалуйста, а то все равно не особо понятно

Comment: Гугл - “zipfile примеры” тоже непонятно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('spam.zip', 'w') as myzip:
    myzip.write('as.py')
```